# NODEJS [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js

sometimes i got error when im trying to get request with request module 
code:
    const request = require('request');

```
getRequest("sitelink", {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, null, proxy,
function(data, res){
  log(data);
});

function getRequest(url, headers, setEncoding, proxy, onResult) {
    var r = request;
    if(proxy != null) r = request.defaults({'proxy':'http://' + proxy});
    else r = request;
    r({method: 'GET', url: url, headers: headers, encoding: (setEncoding == null ? 'UTF-8' : setEncoding)}, 
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            onResult(body, response);
            return;
        } else log(error);
    });
};
```

error log:

```
> Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent
> to the client
>     at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:469:11)
>     at ServerResponse.header (/root/bot/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:767:10)
>     at ServerResponse.send (/root/bot/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
>     at /root/bot/start.js:1381:12
>     at Request._callback (/root/bot/start.js:1503:4)
>     at Request.self.callback (/root/bot/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
>     at Request.emit (events.js:182:13)
>     at Request.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
>     at Request.<anonymous> (/root/bot/node_modules/request/request.js:1161:10)
>     at Request.emit (events.js:182:13)
```

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when your app is responding to the client over HTTP - and you try to send the response / response headers twice. Once the response is sent, the connection will be closed.
You can only send them once for a given http request. You can keep a connection open and send more data , but you cannot send the response headers again.

Comment: how can i check can i send res or not?

Comment: can you try to debug your app using Visual Studio code debugger?

Comment: so, where is OP doing that and how can it be avoided?